# Is the Stack Overflow software licensed to other sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, licensing

As well as SO, SuperUser & Serverfault I seem to be seeing the same thing used elsewhere. Are they all run by FogCreek/Joel/whoever, or is the software licensed to 3rd parties? For instance there's a Startup site I saw.

Is there a full list, and information about the software, anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*stackexchange* is the name of the service proposed.

You can visit the website http://stackexchange.com to have more information.

There is a list of stackexchange sites here:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites

The list is not full, but is quite extensive: most users want to appear in the list, but not all.

They are not all run by the same people as SO, Superuser and serverfault.

Comment: As of a few days ago, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites no longer exists. All `meta.stackexchange.com` URLs redirect to the MSO main page.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/) site mentioned by tucson, there are also [**clones**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) out there. Those are obviously not licensed or controlled by Jeff or Joel.