# StackOverFlow Platform

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the Stack Overflow software licensed to other sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36791/is-the-stack-overflow-software-licensed-to-other-sites)

I can see that stackoverflow's Q&A system is used on multiple domains - meta, careers, serverfaults etc etc.

Would StackOverFlow, in the near future allow others to hosts their Q&A sites based on the same platform ?

Comment: List of StackExchange sites: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites

Comment: Not in the future

Answer (score 2):

See [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com).  They are already doing what you suggest.